# how to exit command without using ctrl + d

Tags: linux, terminal, tee

I want to open three terminals and I want to write a command in the first window that will send a `Hello` message to the other two. The command must allow a one-time sending without a response from the other terminals.

I used:

```bash
tee > /dev/pts/1 /dev/pts/2
```

and everything is good, but I want to exit the command after typing `Hello` without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: `Ctrl+C`?  It's unclear what the issue is with marking end-of-input with `Ctrl+D` and it's unclear what you would _like_ to do otherwise.

Comment: It seems you only want to enter one input, something like `read val; echo "$val" | tee /dev/pts/1 /dev/pts/2` perhaps?  (or shorter `read val; echo "$val" | tee /dev/pts/{1,3}`)

Comment: Also: `head -1 | tee /dev/pts/{1,3}`

Comment: `echo Hello | tee …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exit, `tee` needs an end-of-file. If you type normally, Ctrl+d provides this end-of-file.  There are other ways:

```
echo "Hello" |tee > /dev/pts/1 /dev/pts/2
```

provides the EOF after the "Hello".

```
head -1 |tee > /dev/pts/1 /dev/pts/2
```

provides the EOF after the first line.